# postgreSQL throws error on some JSON docs when reading line by line

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to read the jeopardy json file from Kaggle into postgresql. The data comes as an array of json docs. I convert that to a single line json file in python with this code (note that I am only getting the first 50 documents here for testing before I try all 200k):

```
f = open('200k_questions.json')
data = json.load(f) # this is an array of dictionaries
file = open('temp_ut.json','w') # open file to write to
max=50
for i in range(0,max):
    temp = data[i]
    json.dump(temp, file)
    file.write('\n')
file.close()
f.close()
```

The first 4 lines of the resulting file are:

```
{"category": "HISTORY", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'For the last 8 years of his life, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man's theory'", "value": "$200", "answer": "Copernicus", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"}
{"category": "ESPN's TOP 10 ALL-TIME ATHLETES", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds, Giants & Braves'", "value": "$200", "answer": "Jim Thorpe", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"}
{"category": "EVERYBODY TALKS ABOUT IT...", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'The city of Yuma in this state has a record average of 4,055 hours of sunshine each year'", "value": "$200", "answer": "Arizona", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"}
{"category": "THE COMPANY LINE", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'In 1963, live on \"The Art Linkletter Show\", this company served its billionth burger'", "value": "$200", "answer": "McDonald\\'s", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"}
```

In postgreSQL, I successfully execute the following commands from the command line:

```
CREATE DATABASE jeopardy;
CREATE TABLE questions(id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, question jsonb NOT NULL);
```

Then to copy the json docs into postgreSQL, I execute the following:

```
\COPY questions (question) FROM 'C:\Users\malawley\Documents\Northwestern MS\Course 6 MSDS 420 Database\TermPaper\data\jeopardy\temp_ut.json';
```

PostgreSQL generates this error:

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "The" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ..."2004-12-31", "question": "'In 1963, live on "The...
COPY questions, line 4, column question: "{"category": "THE COMPANY LINE", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'In 1963, live on "The Art L..."

The problem is with this document (the first 3 will load successfully):

{"category": "THE COMPANY LINE", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'In 1963, live on "The Art Linkletter Show", this company served its billionth burger'", "value": "$200", "answer": "McDonald\'s", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"}

A couple of other problematic documents are:

{"category": "EPITAPHS & TRIBUTES", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'"And away we go"'", "value": "$400", "answer": "Jackie Gleason", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"}

{"category": "ESPN's TOP 10 ALL-TIME ATHLETES", "air_date": "2004-12-31", "question": "'No. 1: Lettered in hoops, football & lacrosse at Syracuse & if you think he couldn't act, ask his 11 "unclean" buddies'", "value": "$600", "answer": "Jim Brown", "round": "Jeopardy!", "show_number": "4680"}

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? I have checked all 200k documents in python using the function below and they all check out. So, I am stuck.

```
def is_json(myjson):
  try:
    json.loads(myjson)
  except ValueError as e:
    return False
  return True
```

Comment: Well JSON lines is not a valid [text format file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.9.2)

Comment: It's a bit weird that one string value starts with double-quote then single-quote. The JSON parsing that's going on in the `COPY` command appears to see the double-quote surrounding the title as ending the double-quote section that it's in. Or in other words, the single-quote is not parsed meaningfully as a string delimiter.  Which is probably fair enough, given all of the other string values only use a double-quote.   So that's where the problem is. Solution? Harder, because enclosing string in a string is hard.  I'd look to getting python to do the insert directly, rather than dump.

Answer (score 1):

You're being bitten by double escaping.

By default, [`copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-copy.html) assumes the input is "Text Format". This uses `\` as an escape character.

> Backslash characters () can be used in the COPY data to quote data characters that might otherwise be taken as row or column delimiters.

Your `\` are interpreted first by COPY and then what remains is passed to JSON.

For example. This input...

```
{ "question": "'In 1963, live on \"The Art Linkletter Show\" ..." }
```

...is read by `copy` and becomes this...

```
"question": "'In 1963, live on "The Art Linkletter Show" ..."
```

...which is invalid JSON.

---

You'll need to double your escapes.

```
{ "question": "'In 1963, live on \\"The Art Linkletter Show\\" ..." }
```

Or convert the data to a single column CSV and add `format csv` to your `copy`. That might sound silly, but then you can let the [Python csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) handle the escaping for you, and this scales to any number of columns.